# getting error while adding visual webpart

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part

I have created visual webpart which as .net validation control. When i deploy part and try to insert into page i get error

```
This page contains content or formatting that is not valid. You can find more information in the affected sections. + webpart
```

Then i found code which i put in my webpart

```
private const string _ascxPath = @"~/MyProject/Webparts/Mywebpart.ascx";

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        WebPartManager wp = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);

        if (wp.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.BrowseDisplayMode)
        {

            base.CreateChildControls();

            Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);

            Controls.Add(control);

        }
    }
```

But when i debug this code it is not going inside if condition `if (wp.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.BrowseDisplayMode)`

What could be reason?

Also if i forcefully take debugger inside if condition then i get error path is not valid which i have put in variable `_ascxPath` 
What path should i put there?

```
**Update1**
```

Now i am trying to disable validation control as below but i get error

```
object reference not set to instance of object
```

Here is code

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        bool pageIsEditMode = SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit ? true : false;

        if (pageIsEditMode)
        {

            RequiredName.Enabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            RequiredName.Enabled = true;


        }
    }
```

Getting error on line `RequiredName.Enabled = false;`

```
RequiredName is asp validation control
```

Answer (score 1):

The user control which you deploy will be saved inside hive folder inside control templates.


If your path is folder path in solution is

`"MyProject/Webparts/Mywebpart.ascx"`

then the path which you should use will be like this

`"~/_controltemplates/15/MyProject/Webparts/Mywebpart.ascx"`.

If you are checking whether page is in edit mode or display mode then you can use bellow code.

```
bool pageIsEditMode = SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit ? true : false
```

Here `pageIsEditMode` variable will be true if page is in edit mode else it will be false for design mode

```
Update 1
```

If you go the properties window (F4) of `Mywebpart.ascx` file in your solution it will be having the property called **Deployment Location** here you will be having value similar to this format

```
{SharePointRoot}\Template\CONTROLTEMPLATES\MyProject.Webparts\Webparts\
```

here you have to replace the

`\` with `/`

and `{SharePointRoot}\Template\CONTROLTEMPLATES` with `~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/`

and in last add the user control file name in this case `Mywebpart.ascx`

filnal string will be the path of the user control you want to load.

As per my knowledge the object reference not found will come if your control is not initialized or not loaded

Comment: it still gives error for the path. When i open control template folder i cant see my webpart

Comment: As i read in this link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75542/where-are-the-custom-ascx-files-now-sp2013    that you cannot find ascx in 15 hive in sharepoint 2013

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: Please see my updated code and let me know whether it was helpfull

Comment: Deployment location is blank when i press F4. Remember i am using 2013 and i am using visual webpart

Comment: If you create the visual WebPart then there is no necessary of loading the ascx file which is created with that.

 You have to load the ascx file only if you have created it separately.

 How you have added the RequiredName validation control through code in .cs file or control in .ascx.

 If you have added control in .ascx file then there should not be any problem.

If you have added in the code then you should properly call that object or initialize that object please check whether you have added that control properly or not.

Comment: I have added control in .ascx file. If i remove this control from ascx file then there is no issue

Comment: Have you given the property of **ControlToValidate** correctly, it should have the id of the control or text box which you want to validate

Comment: Offcourse i have put correct name